Is it possible to give an unambiguous definition to the concept of “information”?
Webster's Dictionary, for example, shows us the following loop of definitions:

defines information through knowledge

defines knowledge through fact

defines fact through information


Is it possible to define the term “information” without a loop, that is, with the help of some fundamental term?

Without in any way questioning the validity or relevance of your question I would remind you: Read the dictionary long enough and you will find nothing but "loops"

At a fundamental level, we can think of information as being concerned with the ability to make distinctions. If I can distinguish between a switch being in the on position or the off position then I have information about the state of the switch. Specifically, I have one bit of information, which suggests how information may be quantified. There are mathematical ways to define information using probability theory, of which the main one is Shannon information theory. There is a lot more information in the SEP article on information

Shannon entropy is exceptionally cool, but I'm not necessarily sure that it's particularly useful as an overarching model for the human concept of information. Like... "my mom died" and "the values of a bunch of parity bits travelling through an undersea cable" and "the first 3 notes of a song on the radio" might all be roughly equivalent in the amount of information they provide, but vastly different in character

Well, your profile says "programmer", so google Kolmogorov complexity, e.g., https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/information/#SoloKolmChaiInfoLengProg That's certainly unambiguous, like you ask for, but doesn't distinguish between Kaia's "my mom died" and "a bunch of bits". But Kaia's objection refers to semantics, not information, per se. So if you're not worried about that, then I think Kolmogorov complexity is about as good as it gets.

@Kaia - "The amount of information" (in Shannons theory) is always relative to a particular system (a sender and receiver). A message that is very informative to me, may be non-informative to you. (It's actually possible to unrelativize this - in Kolmogorov complexity theory - but that doesn't translate into practically useful applications - I believe - might be wrong.)

@mudskipper My point is that "my mom died" and "the first 3 notes of the song" both provide bits of information to me, assuming I start out not knowing my mom's current state (but last I checked she's still alive) and start out not knowing the song. If we have a random variable H distributed over {momdeath, momlife} x {all songs that could be on the radio} x <lots of other outcomes> according to probability distribution p, we can calculate the information content of seeing momdeath or seeing "that sounds a lot like radioactive - imagine dragons"

shannon entropy works really well when you have a defined "sender" and "receiver" but trying to make the sender "the universe and all states therein" it becomes challenging to make a workable theory for the everyday human, I think

@Kaia - Well, yes, we are struggling to even learn the alphabet of the Book of Nature, and our picture of the sample space is always incomplete. And while we are learning the alphabet, the alphabet may be changing... The indeterminancy of these infinite spaces frightens me.

Will work up an answer here! Shannon entropy is often discussed in terms of the measure of information but what most commenters forget to discuss is what measures are and why it should be relevant that information can be defined as a measure, and I think this is where the explanation of Information gets most fleshed - it is a way to quantify a degree of Selection within a set of options of varying likelihood

If you need a rigorous definition, it might be better to invert the question and look at noise/entropy...

(1) In a dictionary we find impressionistic characterizations of various semantic meanings of words and phrases - meanings that may be tied to very different contexts. If you just pick and choose arbitrary characterizations it's pretty easy to find the kind of loops that you pointed out. Those are really not relevant, since that's not the way a dictionary should be/is intended to be used. A dictionary is not intended as a comprehensive theory of all words in a language.
(2) It's not possible to define every word in terms of other words. Or rather, it is possible, in principle, but it's trivial to see that this would lead to circular chains - like the one you found.
(3.1) It is possible to define information without using a circular chain of definitions. The simplest way, is just stop after the first or second definition. Is that cheating? No. What I'm getting at is: What matters is whether the definition makes sense to you, whether it is a useful definition for whatever you want to do with that term. -- This is not to deny that if you still need clarifications after two steps, and someone would propose the third step, you're perfectly right in saying: "Sorry, you just made a circular definition, I'm still not in the clear about what you meant with your original term."
Ultimately, what matters most, perhaps, is how powerful a definition is (in how many contexts, for how many people, it is useful and brings things together).
(3.2) Claude Shannon gave a powerful definition of information, or rather of what it means to be informative or carry information, without circularity. His definition of x is informative (to somebody, in some context) boils down to x is surprising (to that person, in that context). Something is more informative in sofar as it is more surprising (less probable).

Sorry, I cannot find "surprising" in "A Mathematical Theory of Communication". Be so kind as to give a link to the corresponding work of Claude Shannon.

https://web.archive.org/web/19980715013250/http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/ms/what/shannonday/shannon1948.pdf - page 10 - Theorem 2 - says translated in language which a non-mathematician can understand: the amount of information is the amount of surprise (uncertainty, entropy).

+1 Shannon, and the whizbang tour of semantic frames. The OP should note that the idea that fundamental notions of semantics are rooted in gestalt-like wholes is a central thesis of Filmore and his frame semantics. "The basic idea is that one cannot understand the meaning of a single word without access to all the essential knowledge that relates to that word."

@JD - Thanks for the reference - I didn't know about Filmore. But this was indeed what I had in mind when I said "brings things together".

Information (physics, computer science, cryptography) is a characteristic of the latter of a pair of measurements or a pair of sets of related measurements, whose numerical value is:
I = -log(p(E|C))
Read: The information obtained by measurement of event E under measured conditions C is equal to opposite the logarithm (base 2) of the probability of E given C.
By a convention artfully designed to confuse undergraduates, "probability of event E given conditions C" is abbreviated "probability of event E" and expressed:
I = -log(p(E))
For instance, if we roll two fair dice and sum them, the information obtained by measurement of the number 2 (which will come up on 1 out of 36 possible rolls of a fair pair of dice) is
I = -log(1/36) = 5.170
While if we roll one die first and observe that it is a 1, the information obtained by measurement of the number 2 on the sum of the two dice (which will come up if we roll another 1) is
I = -log(1/6) = 2.585
The mathematical formulation is arbitrary, but it is chosen this way to conform to common use and professional convenience in the following ways:

a message Z times as long will have Z times bigger I for a given specificity of outcome. Note how when we rolled two dice, requiring the two dice to both come up a particular value, I was double the value as when we fixed one of the dice and rolled just one of them.

more surprising outcomes (such as rolling a 2 on two dice, versus rolling a 7) are represented by bigger Information.

the formulation allows for mathematical treatment similar to thermodynamic entropy in mathematical physics.

using a base-2 logarithm makes the maximum information obtained by a measurement whose result is expressible as a base-2 string (such as a computer file), equal to the length of that string. Since most of our information transfer and storage is done in base-2 strings at the moment, it's a convenient choice of logarithm base.



You should inform the questioner that you are attempting to answer the question with Claude Shannon's work on Information Theory, where he establishes a definition based on probabilities.

Definition of information depends heavily on the field of study. Information theory says it is the reduction of uncertainty. In computer science it is processed , organized and structured data. In quantum mechanics it is the state of system. In biology it is DNA , RNA . In communication theory it is the content delivered through communication channel.
However we are missing one field of study which is consciousness. In consciousness, the information develops with the question “what?”. What is that exists ? Earth exists , food exists , smell exists , fire exists, God exists etc etc … In consciousness we are the consumers of that information. Given the base knowledge we ask further questions like Why that exist ? What should we do about it ? Why should we do that ? How should we do that ? When should we do that ? Etc… Information builds up starting with the question “what exists?”
Information at least answers one fundamental question: What exists ?
And both the question and answer depends on understanding in the consciousness. Information can not be seperated from consciousness. Only conscious beings understand what information is.

Unequivocally, yes, information can be defined rigorously. Four starting places to study a rigorous notion of information are Shannon, Chaitain, Floridi, and Shagrir and Piccinini.
Bumble's comment is both canonical and strong. Information theory as a description of a problem space in deciphering messages goes back quite a way to Shannon, a contemporary of Turing, and eventually was adopted into disciplines like control theory. The gist of the position is that a mathematical analysis can be conducted on codes and used to understand meaning. Gregory Chaitain is another towering figure in the study of information. He has pushed a number of important ideas on the relationship of randomness and measures of information. In addition, Luciano Floridi has a sweeping theory of information called The Philosophy of Information (GB) which develops a metaphysically rigorous account of information. Lastly, if you are interested in a rigorous notion of information, you might be interested in the notion of physical computation (SEP), which views information through the lens of physical systems that compute.
